# Several firewalls when creating Google Cloud Platform instance. Which to use?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I created a Google Cloud Platform Ubuntu 16.04 instance. It seems the GCP has several places where traffic can be filtered:

1. The Instances section of the GCP console lets me allow or disallow
   HTTP and HTTPS traffic.
2. In the Networking section I can create additional firewall rules which limit access to the network.
3. Finally, in the Ubuntu instance itself I can configure UFW to block/allow certain ports.

Should I configure all of these? Would it be better to just configure one and allow all in the others?

As a note, this instance will serve a website, so I would only allow HTTP/HTTPS traffic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The complete answer is that *it depends*.

For number one, the only thing that happens is that the `default-allow-http` [rule](https://console.cloud.google.com/networking/firewalls/list) gets applied to that instance.

The networking section is where you define your own rules that what to be applied to instances. It becomes easier to maintain all your networking configs in Google Cloud if you start having multiple instances and load balancers. You can share apply a single rule to some machines and you can compose them.

Finally, I would use ufw/iptables only as a last resort config. For example I have a some machines behind a load balancer and one of them is doing something weird. I would ssh into it and block port 80 and investigate it.